# Image cache size increases loading time

Tags: php, caching, benchmarking

I host a website that as a part of it's service the website creates cool little PNG avatars for users based on their skin in a game. 
I am caching all images in a cache directory for 4 hours to prevent hitting the game's servers and to decrease loading time for the images, but after a year or two of doing this I noticed that load times of avatars increase as there are more cached images in the directory, which looks strange to me because I do not make my script iterate through the entire directorty until it finds the cached image it was looking for.
And here are some benchmarks in cURL:
First test; 400 cached images:

```
-------
    time_namelookup:  0.000
       time_connect:  0.093
    time_appconnect:  0.000
   time_pretransfer:  0.093
      time_redirect:  0.000
 time_starttransfer:  0.452
                    ----------
         time_total:  0.452
```

Second test; after deleting all of the cache:

```
   time_namelookup:  0.000
      time_connect:  0.093
   time_appconnect:  0.000
  time_pretransfer:  0.093
     time_redirect:  0.000
time_starttransfer:  0.249
                   ----------
        time_total:  0.249
```

So, is there any specific reason why the loading time is decreased with less cache in the directory? And is there a way to optimize that?
**Edit**
The way the requests are made is that whenever somebody requests an avatar the script checks if there is a cached image with his username.
It does that with PHP's `file_exists()`

Comment: Is the directory publicly accessible?

Comment: Technically not, but if you know the full URL and a specific filename in the directory you can access it.

Comment: Could you use a rewrite rule? Or an alias?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you familiar with Apache RewriteRules and Aliases?  They allow you to change a request and serve a different file.  You might be able to use the existing requests to serve the images without PHP.

Comment: Negative. the PHP part is necessary because it does a few PHP GD functions before serving the image, including resizing and cutting.

Comment: Can you cache the processed images?

Comment: That's exactly what i do, instead of requesting the skin image from the game servers every time that username's avatar is called, i request it once, and from there work only with the cached version, which is again, adapting the the requested feature and size.

Comment: Does "adapting the the requested feature and size" happen on every request?

Comment: Please show more of your PHP code. How do you pass cached image to the browser? What are you doing to create cache?

Comment: @user2182349 yes it happens on every requesr.

Comment: @Pamelus to create cache i use php's imagepng(); same for redering the cache to the browser.

Comment: Then I recommend finding a way to store the images which have been processed.

Comment: So that's it. Your cache is not actually cache, if you're still processing cached files with ImagePNG(). Use readfile() on cached files instead.

Comment: All images go through the same process, wether cached or not, the only thing that does change, is that if the script detects that there is a cached image available, it will imagecreatefrompng(); from that and not from a remote server.

Comment: That way I don't have to hit the remote server too often and don't have to wait for the remote server to reply, which can  take up to 800 ms on a bad day.

Comment: As @pamelus said - your cache isn't fully caching, you're still processing the images on every request.

Comment: Yes, i have to, otherwise the cached avatar will only be available in one size for the next 4 hours. The caching is mainly there to minimize external connections. But the site can't do without further processing of the image afterwards